# unable to parse API value

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, reactjs

```
{
id: 8,
customerName: "xyz",
customerMobileNumber: "123456789",
customerBillingAddress: "xyz address",
customerShippingAddress: "xyz address",
customerProductPurchasedDate: "2021-11-09T09:07:00.000Z",
customerGstNumber: "xyz",
customerHsnNumber: "xyz",
addedInvoiceProductDetails: "[{"productquantity":"5","productprice":"5","productgst":"5","productname":"xyz","producttotalprice":"26.25","id":"2021-11-13T09:08:20.071Z"}]",
created_at: "2021-11-13T09:08:25.000000Z",
updated_at: "2021-11-13T09:08:25.000000Z"
},
```

I'm getting above values in one of my project API[**http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/invoice_details/8**], The issue here im facing is that im unable to map the parameter i.e., **addedInvoiceProductDetails** the typeof im getting for the parameter **addedInvoiceProductDetails** is as string. So map wont work for string. Hence how can i convert it to object and map it.

**Note:**  I'm getting the response from API for **addedInvoiceProductDetails** parameter is as below

`[{"productquantity":"1","productprice":"1000","productgst":"18","productname":"Street Light","producttotalprice":"1180","id":"2021-11-18T12:11:31.137Z"},{"productname":"Solar","productquantity":"2","productprice":"50","productgst":"10","producttotalprice":"110","id":"2021-11-18T12:11:43.935Z"}]`

The response what im getting from API is parsed one itself, but still when i check its typeof it is giving as string.

it would be really helpful if i have provide with solution, im stuck with this issue from past 2 days.

Comment: I assume there are some `\\` in that string?

Comment: yes !!! im console when i try it in response im getting '\' but when i print it im not getting '\'

Comment: What does your fetch/axios/ajax call look like?

Answer (score 1):

You need to JSON.parse the value

```js
const response = [{
    id: 8,
    customerName: "xyz",
    customerMobileNumber: "123456789",
    customerBillingAddress: "xyz address",
    customerShippingAddress: "xyz address",
    customerProductPurchasedDate: "2021-11-09T09:07:00.000Z",
    customerGstNumber: "xyz",
    customerHsnNumber: "xyz",
    addedInvoiceProductDetails: "[{\"productquantity\":\"5\",\"productprice\":\"5\",\"productgst\":\"5\",\"productname\":\"xyz\",\"producttotalprice\":\"26.25\",\"id\":\"2021-11-13T09:08:20.071Z\"}]",
    created_at: "2021-11-13T09:08:25.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-11-13T09:08:25.000000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    customerName: "xyz",
    customerMobileNumber: "123456789",
    customerBillingAddress: "xyz",
    customerShippingAddress: "xyz",
    customerProductPurchasedDate: "2021-11-11T09:26:00.000Z",
    customerGstNumber: "xyz",
    customerHsnNumber: "xyz",
    addedInvoiceProductDetails: "[{\"productquantity\":\"5\",\"productprice\":\"5\",\"productgst\":\"5\",\"productname\":\"gggg\",\"producttotalprice\":\"26.25\",\"id\":\"2021-11-13T09:27:17.639Z\"}]",
    created_at: "2021-11-13T09:27:20.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-11-13T09:27:20.000000Z"
  },
]

response.forEach(({addedInvoiceProductDetails})=> console.log(JSON.parse(addedInvoiceProductDetails)))
```